# Palabra en manuscrito

Tags: identificación-de-término, escritura-manuscrita

¿Alguien sabe qué palabra está escrita en la antepenúltima línea donde dice:

> (...) que el día 30 treinta del mes ____ pasado a las...

[image]

Comment: ¿Podrías dar algo de contexto sobre el texto?

Comment: A mí me parece que pone "proximo" (que debería ser "próximo").

Comment: Es un acta de nacimiento de principios de 1900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según lo que veo, se lee la expresión `del mes próximo pasado` (donde la palabra en duda aparece sin acento)

> (...) que el día 30 treinta del mes ***proximo*** pasado a las...

En cuanto a la expresión, entiendo que es una forma comúnmente usada en documentos y crónicas del castellano antiguo y la América colonial (Ver [resultados de una búsqueda en Google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22proximo+pasado%22)

Creo no equivocarme en haberla visto incluso en documentos formales de escribanías y textos legales actuales (en Argentina). Desconozco si su uso sea aún frecuente en ótros ámbitos.

(Paréntesis para referir que la expresión está en sintonía con la primera definición [que la RAE proveé](https://dle.rae.es/pr%C3%B3ximo) de la palabra próximo, la cual con la palabra `pasado` puede aplicarse a "*inmediatamente* *anterior*")

> Del lat. proxĭmus.

1. adj. Cercano, que dista poco en el espacio o en el tiempo.

> 2. adj. Siguiente, inmediatamente posterior. U. t. c. s.

[image: expresión en un texto antiguo]

Comment: Yo también leo eso, pero la expresión "el mes próximo pasado" se me hace rara. Tal vez convendría investigar si es (o fue) de uso común en algún país o ámbito concreto.

Comment: Buena idea, en cuanto a mi no me pareció nada rara por que la reconozco como un expresión usada

Comment: @Charlie:   Aquí habla el [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/pasado-proximo-2074/) de esta expresión.

Comment: La expresión "próximo pasado" era una expresión habitualmente usada en documentos legales para indicar el día/mes/año pasado más cercano, es decir el último.